# Rails model one of one value but multiples of others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, attachment

I have a rails application that has a field called main_image, which is boolean, in the attachment model.  It is suppose to allow only one true but multiple false in the database, however as I have the scope now it only allows one of each for each asset, which is another model. How would allow multiple false but only one true per attachment?

Comment: Go ahead and move your edit to an answer and set it as the accepted answer. That way people won't click on it thinking there are no answers (like I did)

Comment: I would have, I will see if it will allow me to do it now.  There is a time restriction on when or I would have done it already (for users with less than 100 reputation points)

Comment: Ok I have posted my answer but it won't let me accept for 2 days.

Comment: I upvoted your answer which pushed you over the 100 mark

Comment: @Robert Rouse, even though it has been up-voted and I am over the 100 mark I cannot accept it until tomorrow.  The over 100 is required to post your own answer (hence the edit in the first place)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now solved this issue by using the following code in my model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :main_image, :scope => [:asset_id], :if=>:main_image
```

since :main_image is either true or false this says to take the main_image field and make sure it is unique for each asset_id only if it is true, because if it is not true it will return false and thus skip checking if the model is unique.